# How to send logs with different levels to different appenders using log4j2.properties file?

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm using `log4j2` and am trying to have different log messages go to different appenders within the same logger.  This case is described exactly in the [log4j2 FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level) - but I need to use the **log4j2.properties** configuration file instead of the XML configuration given in the example.

Another example with an XML configuration file is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778831/log4j2-multiple-loggers-to-multiple-appenders-at-different-logging-levels) - essentially, I don't know how to specify the lines

```
<AppenderRef ref = "Console" level ="info"/>
<AppenderRef ref = "hibernateFile" level = "debug"/>
```

in `log4j2.properties` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below syntax -

```
rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = file
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.level = DEBUG
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.level = INFO
```